# KB2524478 Not applicable

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-update

Good afternoon guys,

I have a headache from a few years back giving me issues.  I have 2 computers that randomly drop from Domain to Public and back to Domain on their network profiles.  I looked it up and the fix should be KB2524478 but when I download it the result is that it is not applicable to my windows 7 Pro Desktop computer.  I have done some searching and I see other people are having this issue when it comes to WSUS.  I verified it is not in my WSUS but a manual install fails too.  I am not however seeing a fix to it.  Does anyone know if this fix was rolled into another update and if so, which one it is so I can make sure it is downloaded?

Comment: KB2524478 is included in KB2775511 [An enterprise hotfix rollup is available for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2775511).

Comment: I have checked that and I dont have it installed on the computers but I also dont have it available in WSUS.  KB2775511.

Comment: Try installing KB2775511 instead of KB2524478

Comment: I am trying that now.  I found it in Microsoft Catalog but now I am having an issue getting into my basket.  This stupid thing keeps giving me an error and I cant actually download the update.

Comment: This update is available from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com). Type 2775511 in the search field that is located in the upper-right corner of the catalog webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this update installed on the machine.  Microsoft Update Catalog and is pain and a half.  it took so long to be able to access my basket to actually download the update.

Comment: You haven't described how you were able to do so, though.

Comment: Well I couldnt do it on the server where the WSUS is running on.  I kept getting an error everytime I tried to check out with the update.  I have to completely reset all of my Internet Explorer settings on my workstation including clearing history and cookies and after 4 or 5 attempts to check out from the Catalog store I was finally able to download it.